# Magento2 custom ExportCsv showing error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.7

I am getting following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCsvFile() on boolean.

I have tried to implement a export CSV in a custom module but it is showing an error.

suyati_scontact_contacts_grid_block.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="admin.block.scontact.contacts.grid.container">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="admin.block.scontact.contacts.grid" as="grid">

                <arguments>
                    <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">contactsGrid</argument>
                    <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Suyati\Scontact\Model\Resource\Contacts\Collection</argument>
                    <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">contacts_id</argument>
                    <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
                    <argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                    <argument name="use_ajax" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Export" name="admin.block.scontact.contacts.grid.export" as="grid.export">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="exportTypes" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportCsv</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="excel" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportXml</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" name="admin.block.scontact.contacts.grid.columnSet" as="grid.columnSet">

                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="contacts_id">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">number</argument>
                            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">contacts_id</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">contacts_id</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                   <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="name">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">string</argument>
                            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="email">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">string</argument>
                            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">email</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">email</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="mobile">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Mobile</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">string</argument>
                            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">mobile</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">mobile</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="location">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Location</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">string</argument>
                            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">location</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">location</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="pincode">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Pincode</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">string</argument>
                            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">pincode</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">pincode</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                     <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="comment">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Comment</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">string</argument>
                            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">comment</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">comment</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="created_date">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created Date</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">string</argument>
                            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">created_date</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">created_date</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Suyati\Scontact\Controller\Adminhtml\Contacts

```
<?php
    namespace Suyati\Scontact\Controller\Adminhtml\Contacts;

    use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

    class ExportCsv extends \Suyati\Scontact\Controller\Adminhtml\Contacts
    {
        /**
         * Export contacts grid to CSV format
         *
         * @return ResponseInterface
         */
        public function execute()
        {
            $this->_view->loadLayout();
            $fileName = 'contacts.csv';
            $content = $this->_view->getLayout()->getChildBlock('admin.block.scontact.contacts.grid', 'grid.export');

            return $this->_fileFactory->create(
                $fileName,
                $content->getCsvFile($fileName),
                DirectoryList::VAR_DIR
            );
        }
    }
```

Controller/Adminhtml/Contacts.php

```
<?php

namespace Suyati\Scontact\Controller\Adminhtml;

abstract class Contacts extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $resultForwardFactory;
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory
     */
    protected $_fileFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $context->getResultRedirectFactory();
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Suyati_Scontact::contact_manage');
    }

    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu(
            'Suyati_Scontact::contact_manage'
        )->_addBreadcrumb(
            __('Scontact'),
            __('Contacts')
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs when it fails to get the layout file. It seems like you have missed the layout xml file where you should specify the grid that has to be exported. In your case you should have

> suyati_scontact_contacts_exportcsv.xml

with the below contents within the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="suyati_scontact_contacts_grid_block"/>
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container" name="admin.block.scontact.contacts.grid.container" template="Magento_Backend::widget/grid/container/empty.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following line in your code:

```
$content = $this->_view->getLayout()->getChildBlock('admin.block.scontact.contacts.grid', 'grid.export');
```

must be your grid block (Which extended `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended`) like

```
$content = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('VENDOR\NAMESPACE\Block\Adminhtml\Product\View\Grid');
```

When you look at

`\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended`

there is function `getCsvFile()`

Hope you get the some clue from this

Comment: i have tried this but it seems to be my grid has some issue

Comment: Ok, try to solve your grid issue, After that try this, It will work for you. @Naveen

Comment: $content = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('VENDOR\NAMESPACE\Block\Adminhtml\Product\View\Grid');in which file i want to add this code

Comment: Just replace your line with my line and make sure about your gid class @Naveen

Comment: No luck means  ? Any error ? Post your full code here, so someone can helps you on this @Naveen

Comment: full code has given please check